# PHP Equivalent of Java's @Override When Implementing Interface (For check style)

Tags: php, overriding, phpdoc, phpcs

`PHPCS` is complaining about `php doc` for implementations of interfaces that already have the `php doc` provided in the interface.

My question is, how do I cleanly get `PHPCS` to ignore interface method implementations, similar to java's `@Override`?

Below is an example of how I do it in java and what I have in php. My goal is to be able to ignore it for methods from interfaces that already have php doc. If the method is not a implementation, then it should still be required to have a php doc provided.

**How it Works in Java**

In java, I can have an interface like so:

```
public interface Sandbox {
    /**
     * Description of some method.
     */
    void someMethod();
}
```

And a class that implements it as so:

```
public class SandboxImpl implements Sandbox {
    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
        // This is the concrete implementaiton.
    }
}
```

With the above, java picks up the java doc without any issues and the @Override helps get past any check style checks.

**What I have in PHP**

In php, I have an interface like:

```
interface Sandbox
{
    /**
     * Some php doc.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function someMethod();
}
```

With a class that implements it like:

```
class SandboxImpl implements Sandbox
{
    public function someMethod()
    {
        // TODO: Implement someMethod() method.
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you already try with inheritDoc tag?

Comment: @awons, I'll test it out. If it works, I'll have you write it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @awons, that annotation didn't work at least for what my team has setup. It specifically looks for the @param and @return. The guys where I work say they got the check style standards from the symphony2 standards. I think I'm going to have to get a little more familiar with how the `php doc` and `PHPCS` stuff work together and see if there is a way to get it to work properly, either with that annotation or other means. I'll have to come back to this when I have time.